# Unhelpful output from pytest

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest, pytest-django

TLDR: How can I get better output from pytest?

I'm using Django with regular python3 unittests.
I've just switched to pytest-django for running tests.

pytest throws an error for almost all my tests (149 in total).
Pages and pages with this error.

```
self = <RegexURLResolver 'project.urls' (None:None) ^/>

    @property
    def reverse_dict(self):
        language_code = get_language()
        if language_code not in self._reverse_dict:
            self._populate()
>       return self._reverse_dict[language_code]
E       KeyError: 'en-us'
```

Which wasn't the problem. It led me down to a wrong path.

I had a syntax error in one of my `views.py` files.
`./manage.py test` resulted in:

> `snip`
>
> File "/home/roland/project/views.py", line 20
>       code = zip(list1, list2])
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Notice the last: `]`  which was the problem.

So: How can I get more useful output on problems when using pytest?

Btw: 
After finding this and scrolling back into the pytest output there was mention of the syntax error. It was just buried in the output.

Comment: I do not use django as much, but my experience with pytest is that once there is a lot of error  messages, something is really broken and not in the messages. I usually resort to running the file or package to detect what is wrong, with definitely catches an error like in your example. It would be nice if pytest could do more magic, but seems it is not as good at trivial mistakes. After al this is a tool to test runnable code, not a linter, not a debugger.

Comment: @Roland you can use the maxfail option (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html) so it will stop immediately on first failure. You can run pytest from the command line with the '--maxfail=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [--maxfail=1](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html) option so it will stop immediately on first failure.

Also, make sure your pytest.ini is setup properly so that pytest knows it should be using django-pyest.

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myapp.settings'
```

For my workflow, I usually do the following:

- run `pytest --maxfail=1 myfile.py &> pytest-output.txt`
- tail, grep, or search he text file for errors.
- Fix and iterate

There are a lot of other configuration options that will help you to get more meaningful input from pytest.

Comment: The `--maxfail=1` option identified the syntax error problem correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Can you please accept the answer when you get a chance! Cheers.